# How do you declare and wire a prototype scoped bean using Spring 4 Java based contexts?

Tags: prototype, autowired, spring-4

I'm a Spring 4 newb.
So if I have a Singleton how do I wire beans of various scopes into it?

I've seen no examples of this.  Is it because it's been abstracted away so that all you have to do is apply @Scope("prototype")?  That would explain the absence of information but it's hard to search for what isn't there. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[2.2.5. Specifying bean scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html#specifying-bean-scope)

Apparently there is a special guide or subsection for handling JavaConfig.